# Arduino compilation error: Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266WiFi.h" . (Wemos D1 R2 Mini / ESP2866)

Tags: c++, oop, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to compile a project in the Arduino IDE, for a D1 mini / ESP286 board.
The code is using a WiFiServer, in the library package:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
```

I'm including this in a couple of different files in the project.

I also have two type of global constant header files: vars.h, and a Colors.h/Colors.cpp class. The Colors.h header basically just has color definitions, and I include this in a couple of other files for usage of the colors.

However, when compiling, I get these types of errors, namely that it's finding multiple libraries for ESP2866WiFi.h, and also that all my variables defined in the included header files have 'multiple definitions', but the header files use the #ifndef/#define/#endif paradigm, but maybe I'm not doing this correctly.

Haven't really programmed in C++ in ages, so please forgive my potentially novice mistakes. I'd appreciate any advice!

When compiling, Arduino IDE terminal is giving:

```
> /Users/rw3iss/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld:
> sketch/Module.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:18: multiple definition of
> `yellow'; sketch/Colors.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:18: first defined here
> /Users/rw3iss/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld:
> sketch/Module.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:19: multiple definition of
> `orange'; sketch/Colors.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:19: first defined here
> /Users/rw3iss/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld:
> sketch/Module.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:16: multiple definition of
> `green'; sketch/Colors.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:16: first defined here

> Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266WiFi.h"  Used:

> /Users/rw3iss/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi
> /Users/rw3iss/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld:
> sketch/Module.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:15: multiple definition of `cyan';
> sketch/Colors.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:15: first defined here
> /Users/rw3iss/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld:
> sketch/Module.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:14: multiple definition of `blue';
> sketch/Colors.cpp.o:sketch/Colors.h:14: first defined here
/Users/rw3iss/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3- 
20ed2b9/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: 
sketch/utils.cpp.o:sketch/vars.h:6: multiple definition of `ssid'; 
sketch/AppServer.cpp.o:sketch/vars.h:6: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini.
```

I don't exactly know if these are even errors, but they're red in the console, and then compilation fails, without an explicit error so much. I'd like to know if I'm including these variables/global kinds of constants correctly. It did compile before I rewrite all the single-file/functional approach to class-based stuff as this is.

I uploaded all of the code here, there's not too much going on, if anyone feels like taking a look:
https://github.com/rw3iss/rgb_light

If I want to use variable definitions throughout my project, defined in Colors.h, I only have to include that file in ever file that references a color variable, correct? This will potentially include the color definitions multiple times, but doesn't this:

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H
 // "global" variables here, or class definition, etc
#endif
```

approach in header files prevent this?

Comment: yes, use guard defines

Comment: Thanks @Juraj I think I'm doing that property in all my header files (can see in above repo). Not sure why it's still complaining about multiple definitions.

Comment: you can't give variables values in .h. values must be in .cpp. you can make them known for other cpp in .h with extern keyword